# HTML-CSS cross-browser color issue

Tags: html, css, colors, cross-browser

I am using the following CSS code within a html page in order to set the H1 and H2 color values.

```
<style type="text/css">
img
{border-style: none;}
H1 {color: "#33CCFF"}
H2 {color: "#33CCFF"}
</style>
```

This is working fine for Internet explorer, but is failing for Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

How do I fix this issue to support all browsers?

Thanks

Comment: Colors in CSS usually don't have quotes around them. Try: `{color: #33CCFF;}`

Answer (score 5):

you need remove '"' around color

- ; goes at the end of the css declaration always, like this:

H1 {color:#FFF;width:100%;}
H1#ID.class {color:#FFF;width:100%;} <==== right order for combining ID's + Class

Comment: Using the checker http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ greatly helps in detecting errors like this.

Comment: Indeed I need to start using the w3c validator more often XD...

Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotes as Voodoo says, but you should also really be closing the color declaration with a semicolon (;). It may work without it, but you're really asking for trouble. ;)